# Getting activity segment data in real-time - Google Fit Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit

I used to successfully get activity data in real time every 20 seconds by using `TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE`, which has since been deprecated. The alternative the docs point toward is [`TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT): the activity performed in a given timeframe. I have successfully subscribed to `TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT` with `FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE`.

I have tried to find DataSources using the SensorsClient as I did with activity sample, as so:

```
Fitness.getSensorsClient(this, account)
            .findDataSources(
                    new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
                            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                            .build())
```

An onSuccessListener is added (actListener being a public variable):

```
.addOnSuccessListener(
    new OnSuccessListener<List<DataSource>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
            for (DataSource dataSource : dataSources) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Act Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Act Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                 // Register listener for receiving activity segment:
                 if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
                                        && actListener == null) {
                     Log.i(TAG, "Data source for ACTIVITY_SEGMENT found!  Registering.");
                     // Register data listener for activity segment:
                     registerActDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT);
                 }
            }

            // If no data sources have been found:
            if (actListener == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "No data sources found for TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT");
            }
```

The List of DataSource objects is empty when I debug it, hence no datasources are found for this particular data source request.

Is this the way I should be going about this, or should I be using the History API to retrieve segments from the Fit store? This seems inefficient since I want to find the activity every 20 seconds as stated, and would require making requests to the Fit store that often, using mobile data/Wifi.

Activity segment sounds more like an aggregate data type than activity sample, but the [docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/public) state it is an instantaneous reading.

I may be going about this wrong and just trying to retrofit the code that worked for activity sample, but I'm not sure; any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I only need the current activity to determine the behaviour of the app, I don't need to write a custom session to the Fit store, unless it's required to read the current activity.